# rails 3.1 can't compile assets on prod due to asset host config

Tags: ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My production asset_host config looks like this:

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request| 
    if request.ssl? 
      "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}" 
    else 
      "#{request.protocol}assets#{(source.length % 4) + 1}.example.com" 
    end 
  }
```

...which is more or less straight from the docs:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

When I go to assets:precompile, I get this:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile 
rake aborted! 
This asset host cannot be computed without a request in scope. Remove 
the second argument to your asset_host Proc if you do not need the 
request.
```

....except that I can't really remove the 2nd arg because I need to 
know if the request is ssl or not.  That said, I understand that a 
request isn't present during the rake task to generate the assets....

So how do I get out of this catch 22?

Answer (score 18):

This will happen when (1) your assets use paths, for example:

```
background:url(image_path('awesome-background.gif'))
```

and (2) your `asset_host` is set to a lambda/proc that requires the second argument (`request`).

Your options are to either remove the `request` argument (if you don't actually use it) or make it optional (and handle the case where it is `nil`). This is easy in Ruby 1.9 (and should be easier, see notes):

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = ->(source, request = nil, *_){
  # ... just be careful that request can be nil
}
```

If you want to be compatible with Ruby 1.8, there is no direct way to create a Proc/lambda with parameters with defaults, but you can use:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |*args|
  source, request = args
  # ...
end
```

Or do it using a method:

```
def MyApp.compute_asset_host(source, request = nil)
  # ...
end

config.action_controller.asset_host = MyApp.method(:compute_asset_host)
```

*Notes:*

1. Your block can return `nil` to signify the "default host", no need to use `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"`
2. In theory you don't need to specify the protocol; a url starting with `//` should use the default protocol (http or https). I'm saying "should" as it looks like [IE <= 8 will download the css assets twice](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5a-missing-schema-double-download/) and I've ran into problems with PDFkit.

So in your particular case, your `asset_host` can be simplified to:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request = nil, *_| 
  "//assets#{(source.length % 4) + 1}.example.com" if request && !request.ssl? 
}
```

*Edit*: Use a lambda or else the `*_` to avoid a [<strike>bug</strike> feature of Ruby](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5694).

Comment: Shouldn't that `if request && request.ssl?` be `unless request && request.ssl?`

Comment: @EricKoslow: Oh, right, I reversed part of the condition. Fixed, I think :-)

Answer (score 3):

For ruby 1.8.x, @Marc-Andre's `method(:compute_asset_host)` technique didn't work for me. Even though the method was defined directly above, `` NameError: undefined method `compute_asset_host' for class `Object' `` was raised.

Here's what worked for me:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |*args|
  source, request = args
  if request.try(:ssl?)
    'ssl.cdn.mysite.com'
  else
    'cdn%d.mysite.com' % (source.hash % 4)
  end
end
```

Comment: I've edited my example with an explicit scope, to make it clearer. Your suggested Proc is good, so I've also incorporated it. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Rails bug. Fixed.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2947

Comment: As you know, the fix was reverted!